# Как сделать таймер на каждые 30 дней

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Всем привет, проблема в следующем, у меня есть подписка на премиум аккаунт, который должен быть на аккаунте 30 дней ( допустим если день заказа был 01.01.2022 в 11:32, то премиум должен закончиться 31.01.2022 11:32 ), вопрос как это сделать, у меня время и статус премиум аккаунта хранятся в базе данных phpmyadmin.
Я пытался сам сделать, но у меня выходило только по фиксированной дате, допустим каждые 10 числа месяца премиум исчезает, и то, когда я есть на странице, а мне нужно, чтобы фиксировано было и даже если никого нету на странице.

```
 $datenow = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Kiev'));
            $date = $datenow->format('i:s');
            $stack = $datenow->format('H:i:s');

            $data = '30:00';

            if ($date == $data){

              $resultul = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `game` ORDER BY dice+updice DESC LIMIT 1");           
              while ($ulist = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultul))
              {  
                $a = mysqli_query($as,"SELECT SUM(dice) FROM game");
                $b = mysqli_fetch_array($a);
                $c = $b[0];
                $dice = $ulist['dice'];
                $updice = $ulist['updice'];
                $img = $ulist['img'];
                
                $userwin = $ulist['username'];

                $query  = "UPDATE users SET money = money + $b[0] WHERE username='$userwin' LIMIT 1";
                $q = mysqli_query($as, $query);
              }
```

Прошу помочь, спасибо

Comment: Покажите, что вы делаете, как делаете и где возникают проблемы

Comment: Обновил, добавил код, который я использовал в своем другом проекте и от туда взял на этот проект, тоисть когда я есть на сайте и время 30:00 ( 30 минут ) то все нормально и ,в случае с данным кодом, игровые коины переходят победителю ( кто первый по сумме коинов, тому все остальные идут), а мне нужно чтобы когда я офлайн и на сайте тоже никого нету, чтобы это все работало

Comment: *хранятся в базе данных phpmyadmin* Вообще-то phpmyadmin всего лишь клиентский интерфейс к базе данных.

Answer (score 5):

> у меня есть подписка на премиум аккаунт, который должен быть на аккаунте 30 дней ( допустим если день заказа был 01.01.2022 в 11:32, то премиум должен закончиться 31.01.2022 11:32 ), вопрос как это сделать, у меня время и статус премиум аккаунта хранятся в базе данных phpmyadmin.

Задача решается чисто средствами MySQL, без привлечения кода PHP. Используется встроенный [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).

Модель процесса:

Допустим, сведения хранятся в таких таблицах:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INT,        -- идентификатор пользователя
    is_premium BOOLEAN  -- включен ли премиум
);
CREATE TABLE subscriptions (
    user_id INT,           -- идентификатор пользователя
    subscription_date DATE -- дата оформления подписки
);
```

Для того, чтобы установить флаг `is_premium` на аккаунте автоматически при оформлении подписки (при вставке записи о подписке), используем триггер:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_set_premium
AFTER INSERT ON subscriptions
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE users SET is_premium = TRUE WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
```

Для того, чтобы по истечении срока подписки сбросить флаг, используем процедуру события:

```sql
CREATE EVENT ev_clear_premium
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
UPDATE users
SET is_premium = FALSE
WHERE is_premium = TRUE
  AND NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT NULL
    FROM subscriptions
    WHERE users.user_id = subscriptoins.user_id
      AND subscriptions.subscription_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY )
```

То есть - если у юзера установлен премиум, но нет записи о подписке свежее 30 дней - сбросить премиум.

И триггер, и процедура создаются однократно и работают, пока их не удалят (процедуру - можно отключить без удаления). И, конечно, надо не забыть активировать Event Scheduler.

---

PS. Гораздо разумнее хранить не факт наличия подписки `is_premium BOOLEAN`, а срок её окончания `premium_till DATE`. А по окончании сбрасывать на NULL. Тогда, во-первых, для сброса не надо привлекать таблицу подписок, отслеживание и сброс выполняется только по таблице пользователей, во-вторых, решается проблема продления срока (т.е. если на момент подписки режим премиум уже был активен - просто добавляем 30 дней к имеющемуся сроку).

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INT,        -- идентификатор пользователя
    premium_till DATE   -- срок действия премиум
);
CREATE TABLE subscriptions (
    user_id INT,           -- идентификатор пользователя
    subscription_date DATE -- дата оформления подписки
);
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_set_premium
AFTER INSERT ON subscriptions
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE users SET premium_till = COALESCE(premium_till, CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 30 DAY
WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
```

```sql
CREATE EVENT ev_clear_premium
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
UPDATE users
SET premium_till = NULL
WHERE premium_till < CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: у вас наверно небольшая ошибка в последнем варианте, в триггере вы устанавливаете дату окончания премиума в +30 дней, а в евенте вы проверяете дату на -30 дней

Comment: @Tunker Вы правы. Счас поправим... готово. Спасибо!